# php combine two arrays with matching array key

Tags: php, arrays

I am new with PHP language so please try to help me. Now I have two array and I want to combine second array with first array by matching with their key.

Thanks :)

**First array looks like this:**

```
Array
(
    [project_virtual_tour] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [project_appartment_plans] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [project_video] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [project_photo] => Array
        (
            [name] => sample.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php32JYlt
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 3616
        )

    [project_aerial_view] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [project_marker] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

**And second array looks like this:**

```
Array
(
    [project_virtual_tour] => 14049071781773982829
    [project_appartment_plans] => 14049071781048072432
    [project_video] => 14049071781875011761
    [project_photo] => 14049071781835183205
    [project_aerial_view] => 14049071782034653259
    [project_marker] => 14049071781245067296
)
```

**And I want result like this:**

```
Array
(
    [project_virtual_tour] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
            [timestamp] => 14049071781773982829
        )

    [project_appartment_plans] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
            [timestamp] => 14049071781048072432
        )

    [project_video] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
            [timestamp] => 14049071781875011761
        )

    [project_photo] => Array
        (
            [name] => sample.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php32JYlt
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 3616
            [timestamp] => 14049071781835183205
        )

    [project_aerial_view] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
            [timestamp] => 14049071782034653259
        )

    [project_marker] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
            [timestamp] => 14049071781245067296
        )

)
```

Comment: It looks like a simple `foreach()` loop should do it. Please give it a try, that's how you learn. You won't learn how to program by getting others to do it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple foreach loop will do the trick:

```
foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
   if (isset($array1[$key]))
      $array1[$key]['timestamp'] = $value;
}
```

Also Barmar's comment is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the Second array to look like:

```
Array
(
    [project_virtual_tour] => Array([timestamp] => 14049071781773982829)
...
```

Then you could do

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
    array_merge($value, $second[$key]);
}
```